# What is the syntax for setting a property to a negative value?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to set a property on a node to a negative number but am hitting syntax errors

Query

```
MATCH (n:SomeNode {myID:1})
SET n.myNegativeNumber=-1
return n
```

Error:

```
Invalid input '-' (line 2, column 24)
"SET n.myNegativeNumber=-1"
                        ^
(Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax)
```

I would add it as a string however I would like to be able to call sum/avg/etc on the property and it doesn't appear that those functions coerce the value to Number in my testing.  Is there correct syntax to set the value as a Number?

Note:  I'm trying this via the packaged web client as well as nodejs module seraph.  Same result in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a space between the `=` and `-`:

```
MATCH n
SET n.myNegativeNumber = -1
RETURN n
```